# How to properly Gulp compile a Service Worker?

Tags: angular, gulp, service-worker

I'm working on a new service worker for our Angular 1.5.x application. My concern before sending it into production is our Gulp process which compiles all application javascript into one minified file and all vendor javascript into a second minified file. I'm using the service worker to cache the javascript and css files since I believe it will seriously speed up the application load on repeat returns, and we are only updating the site every few months, so I figure I can update the service worker using version control (*please also let me know if I have that wrong*). My question is **do I need to separate out the javascript file for my service worker in my gulp process** to a third file?

I'm not positive how the registered service workers act and I wouldn't want the service worker to accidentally get cached and then to no longer have the ability to update the service worker. I would really appreciate any explanation or links you can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to generate a separate file for the service-worker.

The browser respects the header cache-control time of your sw file and it updates the your service-worker when there's a byte-diffrent to the existing one.

See [The Service Worker Lifecycle => Updating the service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle)

And if you use version-specific caches don't forget to rename your cache.